# Why does Oracle round up a number with less than 38 significant digits?

Tags: oracle

We have Oracle Server 10.2.

To test this, I have a very simple table.

```
CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.TESTNUMBER
(
  TESTNUMBER  NUMBER
)
```

When I try to insert **0.98692326671601283** the number gets rounded up.

```
INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.TESTNUMBER (TESTNUMBER) 
VALUES (0.98692326671601283);
```

The select returns:

```
select * from TESTNUMBER
```

> 0.98692326671601**3**

It rounds up the last 3 numbers "283" to "3".

Even looking at it with TOAD UI and trying to enter it with TOAD, I get the same result.
Why? Is it possible to insert this number in an Oracle number without it getting rounded up?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref118 and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i140176 and http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name those links are the reason I am confused, I thought NUMBER was treated different than floating point numbers. As you can see in the first ink you sent "Binary floating-point numbers differ from NUMBER in the way the values are stored internally by Oracle Database. Values are stored using decimal precision for NUMBER."

Comment: The first link states "*Specify a floating-point number using the following form: `NUMBER `*" and in the second link "*Such a storage scheme cannot represent all values using decimal precision exactly*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so you think the number gets rounded up because it can not be represented in binary?

Comment: Correct, because a floating point number is an approximate data type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought so too before asking, but checking on this site http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/, it would seem the number should get rounded down.

Comment: So how does that site know how Oracle stores such a number?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just checked, oracle does not use floating point types when you specify a literal decimal, it is of type NUMBER unless you add 'f' or 'd' postfix.

Comment: @eckes that is what understood that is why I am confused.

Comment: Dzyann I think the answer from Dave is the correct one.

Comment: Besides the sqlplus formatting, when you use a programming language, you might need to store it in aproperiate objects (`String` or `BigDecimal` in Java)

Comment: @eckes it looks like it, I will check it out. I got a doubt though, number doesn't use floating point to store? It uses decimal precision to store?

Comment: Yes, number stores 2 digits in one byte (00-99). It has 20 bytes. The first has special meaning, so you have 19*2=38 digits before and after the decimal. The numbers can be larger than that if leading or trailing digits are zero:   "1234567890123456789012345678*10^-62" would be I guess possible.

Comment: @eckes yes that I was aware of. But I was looking at it in the client. I didn't think I would get the issue there.

Comment: @Dzyann Toad does honor COL statements similar to sqlplus.

Comment: Great! Thanks @eckes, my understanding was along those lines but I couldn't find the reference and this issue and users' comments got me confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to look into how your client program displays number values.  An Oracle NUMBER should store that value with full precision; but the value may be rounded for display by the client.

For instance, using SQLPlus:

```
dev> create table dctest (x number);

Table created.

dev> insert into dctest VALUES (0.98692326671601283);

1 row created.

dev> select * from dctest;

         X
----------
.986923267

dev> column x format 0.000000000000000000000000000
dev> /

                             X
------------------------------
 0.986923266716012830000000000
```

As you can see, the default format shows only the first 9 significant digits.  But when I explicitly change the column formatting (a client-side feature in SQLPlus), the full value inserted is displayed.

Comment: At the moment I couldn't make COLUMN work in TOAD, however by simply doing select TO_CHAR(TESTNUMBER) from TESTNUMBER; It works, showing the full precision. Thanks!